# New to string so how to manage this title applier

Tags: java

After reading the string methods description in a chapter i was trying to solve this programming exercise. here it is.
Write a program that asks for the user's name and then writes that name to the monitor with either "Ms." or "Mr." in front, depending if the name is for a female or male. Assume that the only female names are

```
Amy
Buffy
Cathy
```

and that the only male names are

```
Elroy
Fred
Graham
```

All other names will be echoed without a title. The program continues looping until the user hits "enter" without first typing a name.

```
C:\>java Title
Enter a name:
Amy Johnson
Ms. Amy Johnson

Enter a name:
Fred Smith
Mr. Fred Smith

Enter a name:
Zoltan Jones
Zoltan Jones

Enter a name:

C:\>
```

here is my code i know its wrong because i am very confused.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class titleApplier {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          String name;
          String male = {"Elroy" , "Fred " , " Graham"};
          String females = {"Amy", "Buffy", "Cathy"};
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          while(name.hasNext()) {
               System.out.println("Enter a name ");
               name = scan.nextLine();
               if(name.equals(male)) {
                    System.out.println("Mr " + male);
               }
               else if (name.equals(females)) {
                    System.out.println(" Mrs " + females);
               }
               else {
                    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: `String male = "Elroy" , "Fred " , " Graham";` How does this even compile? Read about arrays and I highly recommend you to go through a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/).

Comment: I see, there are some errors where you try to parse all Names given by the user. I suggest you to first write a code that, read each neame and just re-print it. And after this, you can add the Male/female stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You're mostly on the right track, good work!

Instead of storing the names in Strings individually, you could just reference them directly in your if statements as such:

```
if(name.equals("Elroy") || name.equals("Fred") || name.equals("Graham")) {
    System.out.println("Mr " + male);
}
```

Also, since you're providing first and last names, I don't think you should be matching with the equals method, but instead, checking to see if the name contains one of the names:

```
if (name.contains("firstName"))
```

As this looks like homework, try something along the same lines for the women yourself. Let me know if you have anymore questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of errors in your program which need to be corrected.Better give this a try.I have used BufferedReader since the Scanner class causes some problems while taking several input values within a loop.:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class MF{

static boolean search(String arr[],String st){
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i].equalsIgnoreCase(st)==true)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
  String male[]={"Elroy","Fred","Graham"};
String fem[]={"Amy","Buffy","Cathy"};
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while(true){
System.out.println("Enter name:-");
String st=br.readLine();
if(st.equals("")==false){
StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(st);
String tok=str.nextToken();
if(search(male,tok)==true)
System.out.println("Mr."+st);
if(search(fem,tok)==true)
System.out.println("Ms."+st);
}
else
break;
}
System.out.println("Program terminates.");
}
}
```

Comment: You should learn the basic concepts first.You should know about the arrays clearly and then start off with the strings..:-).

Answer (score 0):

A few observations from your code:

1. male and females should be arrays of String, not just a single String. (i.e. `String[] females = {"Amy", "Buffy", "Cathy"};`
2. Watch out for leading and trailing white spaces.  "Fred" and "Graham" will never pass a comparison unless you call the `String.trim()` method.
3. The method `hasNext()` is not defined in the String class; thus the compilation error. If you are writing this on an IDE such as Eclipse, read the errors you are getting and resolve them.  Even for a beginner this should not be difficult at all.
4. Your program prompts the user AFTER the name is already entered. This might be easier if you enclose your code in a `do/while` rather than in a `while` loop. This is a matter of preference, or course.  Also, normally you would want the user input to appear in the same line as the prompt, so use `System.out.print()` for the prompt instead of `System.out.println()`.
5. When you are learning, you should always try your programs with very controlled inputs.  In this case, you should have tried the program with a single male name and female name, and once you got that part working, then you should try expanding your solution to handle multiple names.
6. Your code allows to enter a LINE (words separated by space) rather than a String (array of characters with no white spaces). Therefore, you need to break that line into tokens (words) and examine either the first token (first name) or the second token (last name) and compare it to the names in the array. Otherwise, the `equals()` method will return `false`. This is because 'Elroy Smith' is not equal to 'Elroy'. You can do what I just explained, or use other String methods such as `contains()` or `startsWith()`.
7. You should append the title to the entered *name*, and not the first name in your String array.  Instead of outputting "**Mrs. Amy**",  your program should output "**Mrs. Amy Smith**".
8. Your `while()` clause does not capture this requirement: "The program continutes looping until the user hits "enter" without first typing a name."  This method will always return true even if the line has a length of zero.  Instead, use the `String` entered and loop only if the length of the **String** entered is larger than zero.
9. To eliminate unnecessary processing, you can use a `boolean` variable to see if the name has been found, in order to `break` (exit loop) or `continue` (skip to next iteration).

This is one potential solution (might not be the most effective, but easy for you to follow):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String name;
    String[] males = {"Elroy", "Fred ", " Graham"};
    String[] females = {"Amy", "Buffy", "Cathy"};
    Scanner scan = null;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = scan.nextLine();
        boolean found = false;

        // Search all possible male names
        for (String temp: males)
        {
            if (name.startsWith(temp))
            {
                System.out.println("Mr. " + name + "\n");
                found = true;
                break; // stop looping if found
            }
        }

        if (found) { continue; }  // skip the rest of the loop if name has been found

        // Search all possible female names (only if name has not been found)
        for (String temp: females)
        {
            if (name.startsWith(temp))
            {
                System.out.println("Ms. " + name + "\n");
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (name.length() > 0 && !found)
        {
            // A name was entered but it was never found
            System.out.println("Unknown name entered.\n");
        }
    } while (name.length() > 0);
    scan.close();
}
```

The output:

```
Enter a name: Fred Smith
Mr. Fred Smith

Enter a name: Buffy Vampire Slayer
Ms. Buffy Vampire Slayer

Enter a name: Cathy Doe
Ms. Cathy Doe

Enter a name: 
Exiting program.
```